# can not read the property undefined 'last' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<form name="contest" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Last name:
Last name:

```
function nameselect(){
if(isBlank(" "+document.contest.last.value)){
    document.contest.last.value = "surname"
    document.contest.last.focus();
    document.contest.last.select();
}
}
function isBlank(s){
var len = s.length;
for(var i =0; i<len;++i){
if(s.charAt(i)!="") {return false;} 
}
return true; 
}
```

the nameselect function uses isBlank() fuction to determine if the user made changes to field that resulted in it becoming blank. if the field is left blank,then the field,s value is set to surname, i found an error saying that can not read the propert document.contest.last.value however code seems to be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by `last` ?

Comment: @FastSnail, What is `document.contest` ?

Comment: @raheel almis yes what is `document.contest`?

Comment: <form name="contest" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

<p> Last name:<input type="text" name="last" ONCHANGE="nameselect();"></form>

Comment: @RaheelAlmis, Go through the deleted answer...

Comment: not sure about the error but `isBlank` will always return false as you are prepending the `last` value with a `' '` (space).

Answer (score 0):

To check if an input element is empty, you can just use the below code instead of a separate function

```
// If using the below remember to add id to the input element. Eg
// <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Surname">
if (document.getElementById("myText").value.trim().length === 0) {
    // The input element is empty
}
```

And also there is a placeholder attribute that you could use to show a certain text when the field is empty. An example of this below

```
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="surname">
```